# RestKit local deletion of objects, still appears in mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using RestKit 0.20.3 for my application. It has offline mode, so I have to store objects in local coredata.

Whenever some objects are deleted from server, it sends `deleted = true` attribute in JSON, which I handle in mapping with `deletionPredicate`.
Here is my mapping.

```
- (RKEntityMapping *)meetingsMapping {

    RKEntityMapping *meetingsMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"DBMeetings" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
    meetingsMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = NO;
    meetingsMapping.deletionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shouldBeDeleted = 1"];
    [meetingsMapping setModificationAttributeForName:@"updated_at"];
    meetingsMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];

    [meetingsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                      @"id": @"id",
                                                      @"title": @"title",

                                                      @"start_date_human": @"start_date_human",
                                                      @"start_time_human": @"start_time_human",
                                                      @"finish_date_human": @"finish_date_human",
                                                      @"finish_time_human": @"finish_time_human",

                                                      @"lock": @"lock",
                                                      @"location": @"location",
                                                      @"sample": @"sample",

                                                      @"deleted": @"shouldBeDeleted",

                                                      @"created_at": @"created_at",
                                                      @"updated_at": @"updated_at",
                                                      @"follow_up_id": @"follow_up_id",
                                                      @"total_topics": @"total_topics",
                                                      }];

[meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"tags" mapping:[self tagsMapping]];
[meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"required_participants" mapping:[self contactsMapping]];
[meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"optional_participants" mapping:[self contactsMapping]];
[meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"readonly_participants" mapping:[self contactsMapping]];
[meetingsMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"organizer" mapping:[self contactsMapping]];

return meetingsMapping;
```

}

It is working well, and attributes are removed from local CoreData.

The problem is the method `getObjectsAtPath` still returns all objects in `mappingResult` parameter.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?type=past&page=%i", URL_MEETINGS, pageNo]
                                       parameters:nil
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                              KLog(@"%@", mappingResult.array); // It is returning all objects, not only non-deleted objects 
                                              completionHandler(mappingResult.array, nil);
                                          }
                                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                              completionHandler(nil, error);
                                          }];
```

Suppose if 5 out of 20 objects were deleted, `mappingResult.array` returns 20 records not 15. The 5 deleted records have no data. When I Log `mappingResult.array`, the first 5 records are printed as following:

```
2014-03-27 13:10:14.105 MeetingKing[7851:70b] W restkit.network.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:125 Unable to refetch managed object <DBMeetings: 0xc1cb820> (entity: DBMeetings; id: 0xc1a6a60 <x-coredata://7B9FC7F6-C0E9-4DF5-91AC-D7C49F54B4F5/DBMeetings/t2915CF2E-2D7D-4E29-8B39-B1C51151809410> ; data: <fault>): the object has a temporary managed object ID.
2014-03-27 13:10:14.105 MeetingKing[7851:70b] W restkit.network.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:125 Unable to refetch managed object <DBMeetings: 0xc5b2ed0> (entity: DBMeetings; id: 0xc5d1110 <x-coredata://7B9FC7F6-C0E9-4DF5-91AC-D7C49F54B4F5/DBMeetings/t2915CF2E-2D7D-4E29-8B39-B1C51151809416> ; data: <fault>): the object has a temporary managed object ID.
2014-03-27 13:10:14.106 MeetingKing[7851:70b] W restkit.network.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:125 Unable to refetch managed object <DBMeetings: 0xc58b6a0> (entity: DBMeetings; id: 0xc5d3de0 <x-coredata://7B9FC7F6-C0E9-4DF5-91AC-D7C49F54B4F5/DBMeetings/t2915CF2E-2D7D-4E29-8B39-B1C51151809417> ; data: <fault>): the object has a temporary managed object ID.
2014-03-27 13:10:14.106 MeetingKing[7851:70b] W restkit.network.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:125 Unable to refetch managed object <DBMeetings: 0xc5b50e0> (entity: DBMeetings; id: 0xc5d4af0 <x-coredata://7B9FC7F6-C0E9-4DF5-91AC-D7C49F54B4F5/DBMeetings/t2915CF2E-2D7D-4E29-8B39-B1C51151809419> ; data: <fault>): the object has a temporary managed object ID.
2014-03-27 13:10:14.107 MeetingKing[7851:70b] W restkit.network.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:125 Unable to refetch managed object <DBMeetings: 0xc1ed5a0> (entity: DBMeetings; id: 0xc1c84e0 <x-coredata://7B9FC7F6-C0E9-4DF5-91AC-D7C49F54B4F5/DBMeetings/t2915CF2E-2D7D-4E29-8B39-B1C51151809422> ; data: <fault>): the object has a temporary managed object ID.
```

If I check in DB, there are only 15 records. That's OK.

If I explicitly fetch from DB, it returns 15 records only, That's OK

But in `getObjectsAtPath` callback, the `mappingResult.array` parameter returns 20 records. That's not OK. :(

The problem is `count` of `mappingResult.array` becomes 20 and my `UITableView` displays 20 rows, with 5 rows have no data.

Is there any other callback by RestKit that accurately returns 15 records, so that I would not have to explicitly fetch records from DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mappingResult` is returning the objects that were mapped, that is what it's supposed to do. The fact that some items were subsequently deleted doesn't change that - indeed you have all of the information that you need as you know all of the objects that were mapped and which ones were deleted as a result.

The simple solution is to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to source data for your table view. It will deal correctly with the updates, insertions and deletions and you don't need to do additional work.

Alternatively, you would need to iterate `mappingResult.array` and filter out the deleted items. The best way to verify is to use a check:

```
if (item.isDeleted || item.managedObjectContext == nil) {
    // remove the now invalid item...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @wain, I am using MagicalRecords, and used it for fetching again from DB. It is returning correct records. I was wondering if there may be some other way to achieve this.